# Retrieving Company name from Address Book in Xcode Swift crash

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to retrieve a few entries from the Address Book but in having trouble with the 'Company' name value.

If the contact in the Address Book has the company complete it works ok. But if the contact doesn't it crashes the app (Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code=1, address=0x0).

Ive tried various methods to detect nil but none seem to work. Here part of the code :-

```
func peoplePickerNavigationController(
    peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!,
    didSelectPerson person: ABRecordRef!, property: ABPropertyID, identifier: ABMultiValueIdentifier) {

 let addresses: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property).takeRetainedValue()

      let indx = Int(identifier) as CFIndex

      let address: NSDictionary = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(addresses,
        indx).takeRetainedValue() as NSDictionary

      if address[kABPersonAddressZIPKey as String] != nil {
        postcode = address[kABPersonAddressZIPKey as String] as String
      }

      if address[kABPersonAddressCountryKey as String] != nil {
        country = address[kABPersonAddressCountryKey as String] as String
      }

      if address[kABPersonAddressStateKey as String] != nil {
        county = address[kABPersonAddressStateKey as String] as String
      }

      if address[kABPersonAddressCityKey as String] != nil {
        city = address[kABPersonAddressCityKey as String] as String
      }

      if address[kABPersonAddressStreetKey as String] != nil {
        street = address[kABPersonAddressStreetKey as String] as String
      }


      let recordType = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonOrganizationProperty)
      if recordType != nil {
        company = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonOrganizationProperty)?.takeRetainedValue() as String? ?? ""
      } else {
        println("just a person, not company")
      }
```

Any suggestions?

Many thanks,

Anthony

Comment: Any reason you're setting recordType using kABPersonKindProperty, but company using kABPersonOrganizationProperty?

Comment: edited post. Was leftover from trying other ways to stop the crash.

Comment: still no answer or update?